# Android Socket.io Websocket Transport does not works in SSL

Tags: android, ssl, https, websocket, socket.io

I'm using gottox [socket.io java client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) for an Android chat application. 
 I could connect to both web-socket and Xhr transport in HTTP mode. But when i switch to HTTPS only Xhr mode is working. i used the default SSL Context as below

```
SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getInstance("Default"));
```

This works fine in Xhr mode. But in websocket transport there are no responses or errors.

Comment: could you share your code, how you change transport to only websocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websocket with SSL working in [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync). Using that for now.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

It might be that with new versions `IO.setDefaultSSLContext` and `IO. setDefaultHostnameVerifier` methods are not available. Instead now we can create our own `OkHttpClient` and set the hostname verifier and ssl socket factory etc on it as mentioned on [socket.io-client-java usage](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/master/README.md#usage). Here is the sniplet from there:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                      .hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)
                      .sslSocketFactory(mySSLContext.getSocketFactory(), myX509TrustManager)
                      .build(); // default settings for all sockets 

IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient); 
IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);
```

---

**Initial Answer:**

I had the same issue with `io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0` version of [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) library on Android for long. It used to work fine for `http` protocol, however for `https` protocol it had trouble establishing connection giving `xhr poll errors`.

Following solution works for me without modifying the library itself:

```
// Socket connection
private Socket mSocket;

// Configure options
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
// ... add more options

// End point https 
String yourEndpoint = "https://whatever.yoururl.com"
String yourHostName = "yoururl.com"

// If https, explicitly tell set the sslContext.
if (yourEndpoint.startsWith("https://")) {        
    try {
        // Default settings for all sockets

        // Set default ssl context
        IO.setDefaultSSLContext(SSLContext.getDefault());

        // Set default hostname
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                return hv.verify(yourHostName, session);
            }
        };
        IO.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

        // set as an option
        options.sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
        options.hostnameVerifier = hostnameVerifier;
        options.secure = true;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Instantiate the socket
mSocket = IO.socket(mEndpoint, options);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `IO.setDefaultSSLContext` and `IO. setDefaultHostnameVerifier` are not longer available in version 1.0

Comment: @ffleandro what do you use instead?

Comment: @Dap You can probably now create your own `OkHttpClient` and set the hostname verifier and ssl socket factory etc on it like:

`OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)
  .sslSocketFactory(mySSLContext.getSocketFactory(), myX509TrustManager)
  .build();

// default settings for all sockets
IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient);
IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);`

Comment: @Dap, yes exactly as Shobhit described.

Answer (score 1):

It works but you have to do some modifications on io.socket library.
Instead of using the socketio.jar, import into src folder the io.socket library (You'll find inside socket.io-java-client package). There, you have to edit the WebsocketTransport class.

Here you have the solution

https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/60

```
 public WebsocketTransport(URI uri, IOConnection connection) {
    super(uri);
    this.connection = connection;
    SSLContext context = null;
    try {
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "HarmonyJSSE");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try {
        context.init(null, null, null);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if("wss".equals(uri.getScheme()) && context != null) {
        this.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(context));
    }
}
```

And remember to call the setDefaultSSLSocketFactory like this:

```
socket = new SocketIO();
socket.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault());
socket.connect("https://www.myHttpsServer.com:443/");
```

Hope it helps someone ;)