# How to use HTTPS in Android SocketIO?

Tags: android, https, socket.io

I have developed an `iPhone` application with `socket.io`, it is working fine with `HTTP` and `HTTPS`.

I have developed `Android` application with `socket.io`. I was using `HTTP` it was working fine. Now I am trying to use `HTTPS`. I made some changes, but it is not at all connecting with `server`. Always I am getting `websocket error`.

```
I downloaded the library from https://github.com/socketio/ for iPhone and Android
```

Below is my sample code

```
try {
            HostnameVerifier verifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    // Not doing any validation for testing
                    Log.i(TAG, "Verifying host name ::: " + hostname);
                    return true;
                }
            };
            IO.setDefaultSSLContext(SSLContext.getDefault());
            IO.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(verifier);

            IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
            opts.reconnection = false;
            opts.secure = true;
            opts.transports = new String [] {WebSocket.NAME};

            socket = IO.socket("https://website.com:6001", opts);
            Log.i(TAG, "Initialized socket io");
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "We are connected to server");
                }
            });
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "We are disconnected from server");
                    socket.off();
                }
            });
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Error");
                    for (Object obj : args) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Errors :: " + obj);
                    }
                }
            });
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Timeout Error");
                }
            });
            socket.on("res", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "got response from server");
                }
            });
            socket.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error :: " + e);
        }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I was having the same issue. You are very close to the answer. Checkout the answer on [Android Socket.io Websocket Transport does not works in SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37311623/1306419). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Shobhit, I am using different approach for security. Anyhow I have tried your suggestion. But same issue. Is there any way to use SSL with socket io?