# Socket.io Android HTTPS - Connection Error xhr poll error

Tags: android, node.js, ssl, https, socket.io

I'm developing a chat application with HTTPS. This is the Socket.IO I've used

### Server

First of all I developed the server with node.js and node module `"socket.io": "^1.4.5"`

In the server I have this:

```
var secure = {
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(secure, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

### Clients

I developed the website with https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js

I developed the iOS application with `pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 5.5.0'`

Finally I'm developing the Android application with

```
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0') {
  exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

In the website and in iOS application I haven't problems with the websocket, but when I try to connect the socket in Android application I receive the following error:

> io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error

Thanks

Comment: I am also getting same error in my Android app. But in my case it is only working fine in web, its not working both in iOS and Android apps. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @RizwanSohaib Any solution to it in Android ?

Comment: @RizwanSohaib I was having the same issue. Checkout the answer on [Android Socket.io Websocket Transport does not works in SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37311623/1306419). Hope it helps.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: Now I am getting SSLPeerUnverified Error. "No Peer Certificate"

Comment: try adding IgnoreServerCertificateValidation = true to client options connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to connect through HTTPS and use Nginx as a reverse proxy on the backend, make sure to configure the upgrade options correctly:

```
upstream nodes {
  # enable sticky session based on IP
  ip_hash;
  # Backend nodejs server
  server 127.0.0.1:5500;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  # The host name to respond to
  server_name mysite.com;


  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;


    proxy_pass http://nodes;


    # enable WebSockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

This worked for me in solving this mystic error.

**Source:** https://nhancv.com/android-socket-io-client-v1-0-0-engineioexception-xhr-poll-error/

Comment: In my case it was the correct help. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely a problem with your installed android version using an ssl socket protocol that your server won't accept or vice versa.

I believe this the case, because I have the same problem with Android 4.4.4 but my 5.1.1 tablet works fine.

Another instance we've seen this problem with with our OkHttpClient against a spring server where we had to extend our own DelegateSSLSocket that implements:

```
    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        super.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{TlsVersion.TLS_1_1.javaName()});
    }
```

So I THINK this is a very similar issue.  Anyway, a work around is to update your Android OS to 5.1.1.  If you find another way without updated the Android OS please let me know!

Comment: It still happens to me on Android M and Android N on Nexus 5X

Comment: Finally I use http and not https. I cannot get a solution for it

Answer (score -1):

I hope this resolve your error:

check your authentication header you are sending from browser, iOS and android. Could because of authentication issue.

[Using Socket.IO on android Always Returns XHR Poll Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093221/using-socket-io-on-android-always-returns-xhr-poll-error)

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl

Comment: Please provide answers here rather than using links.