# EngineIOException: xhr poll error in Android + Socket.io

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I have the following error while trying to connect to localhost machine:

```
I/Connection error: Connectio errorio.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
```

My code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Manager;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;
import io.socket.engineio.client.Transport;

public class LoiginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket socket;
    {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loigin);

        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {

                Log.i(TAG,"connected");
            }
        });
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Connectin error" + args[0]);
            }
        }); 

        socket.connect();   


    }
}
```

Internet permissons are set up. [Using Socket.IO on android Always Returns XHR Poll Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093221/using-socket-io-on-android-always-returns-xhr-poll-error) didn't help me

Comment: It seem that someone else had this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093221/using-socket-io-on-android-always-returns-xhr-poll-error)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is going through this.

```
try {
        socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000");

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The OP is trying to connect to the localhost. In this case, localhost refers to the phone itself and probably the socket.io server is not on the phone. 
 To solve this, change "http://localhost" with the machine's (that is serving socket.io) local network ip address.