# (CORDOVA) App is not connecting to sockets api in release mode

Tags: android, cordova, sockets, ionic-framework, release

**(ATTENTION: this is happening just with the tag --release )**

### Problem

I cureently built an ionic app based on sockets connection, everything works just fine when i am in debug mode.. however when i move to release ( --release attribute ) the app is no longer connecting to the api endpoint. sockets is trowing the fallowing message `xhr poll error`

#### What is expected to happen?

connect to the api endpoint.

#### What does actually happen?

not connecting to the api endpoint.

### Information

I am currently using the fallowing packages

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@mapbox/polyline": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "angular-laravel-echo": "git+https://github.com/chancezeus/angular-laravel-echo.git",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.6.2",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "git+https://github.com/razvang10/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy.git",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.6.1",
    "ngx-laravel-echo": "^1.0.26",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "8.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
```

#### Command or Code

ionic cordova build android --release --prod

#### Environment, Platform, Device

Platform: android

Device: any

#### Version information

Cordova : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Ionic: 6.1.0

Operating System: Windows

Android Studio: 3.5

Platform version: API 29

SDK: 26.1.1

Comment: Hey Razvan, is this SO issue helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093221/using-socket-io-on-android-always-returns-xhr-poll-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like after android api level 28 you cannot use any other port than 443 for secure connections... because it will restrict your acces only in relase mode so i changed my sockets port from what i had to 443 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this: I fixed it.

---

To enable `http` traffic it is required to configure both `usesCleartextTraffic` AND `AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled` (due to https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1354) in the Cordova `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/uses-permission" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```

To enable `https` with self-signed certificates, it is helpful to use the plugin `cordova-plugin-certificates` and add the following statement to your source code:

```
window.cordova.plugins.certificates.trustUnsecureCerts(true);
```

---

My working code

Server:

```
import { createServer } from "http";
import { createSecureServer } from "http2";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import fs from 'fs';

console.log("Start Server..");

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./zefau-key.pem', 'utf-8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./zefau-crt.pem', 'utf-8'),
    'allowHTTP1': true,
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}

const httpServer = createServer();
const httpsServer = createSecureServer(options);
const io = new Server({
    // options
    'cors': {
        'origin': (origin, fn) => {
            return fn(null, origin);
        }
    }
});

// attach server to socket
io.attach(httpServer);
io.attach(httpsServer);

// error
io.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error);
});

// connection
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    
    socket.on("message", (message) => {
        console.log('message received: ' + message);
        socket.emit('message', 'hi back');
    });
    
});

httpServer.listen(80, '0.0.0.0');
httpsServer.listen(443, '0.0.0.0');
```

Client Cordova App (App.vue only for testing)

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  beforeCreate() {
            if (window.cordova.plugins.certificates) {
                window.cordova.plugins.certificates.trustUnsecureCerts(true);
            }
  },
    mounted() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            alert("Start Client..");
            
            const URL = "192.168.178.50"; // server host
            
            alert("Connect to " + URL);
            const socket2 = io('http://' + URL);

            socket2.on("connect", () => {
                alert("CONNECTED http");
                socket2.emit('message', 'hi');
            });

            socket2.on("connect_error", error => {
                alert("CONNECT ERROR http (" + URL + "): " + error.message);
            });

            socket2.on("message", message => {
                alert('message received: ' + message);
            });
        });
    }
})
</script>
```

Tested on Cordova v11