# socket_io_client: ^1.0.1 flutter web app cannot connect

Tags: flutter, websocket, socket.io, flutter-web

This is the code I wrote .
This code works fine in ios and android devices. I can connect in android/ios devices

But I get this error in flutter web(chrome):

```
{msg: websocket error, desc: null, type: TransportError}
```

This is my code :

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;
void setupSocketIO() {
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('ws://151.240.60.171:81',
  OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());

socket.onConnect((_) {
  print('connect');
});

socket.onConnectError((data) {
  print(data);
});

socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `.setTransports(['websocket'])`. I don't think that part is meant to be used on Flutter Web since it uses `dart:html`. Maybe like

```
if (kIsWeb) {
  //run without ".setTransports"..
} else {
  //run with ".setTransports"...
}
```

Comment: still does not work in flutter web . now it gives this :{msg: xhr poll error, desc: 0, type: TransportError}

Comment: That means it's working. xhr poll error happens after your websocket is able to connect to something. Unfortunately, xhr poll error can have tons of causes that are unrelated to your code, such as SSL errors and incorrect permissions/credentials. You'll have to gather more information and research on your own. Stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093221/using-socket-io-on-android-always-returns-xhr-poll-error) might help.

Comment: @Sae, I have same error, did you fixed it?

Comment: Seems I can connect via ws but not wss over Google Cloud. The normal app can hmm.